# jqgrid add / delete / modify button call a html page

Tags: html, jqgrid, call, button

i work with jqgrid for listings only also i don't use jqgrid forms
i need to call external forms (example: update.cgi?id=123) to make modifications on the database.
how can i make that ?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Look at the documentation for the 'editurl' parameter.

e.g. editurl: "/GridDemo/GridSave",

Mark your columns as editable, add the appropriate options to the page control too, e.g.

```
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager2',
              {     
                  edit: { height: 280, reloadAfterSubmit: false },
                  add: { height: 280, reloadAfterSubmit: false },
                  del: { reloadAfterSubmit: false }, search: false
              });
```